# Data export to excel & save directly to the directory (folder)

Tags: php, export, cakephp-1.3, export-to-excel

Currently on clicking on export user is `prompt a box` to save/open the export excel file to their system , though what i want is when user click on export/send data , the data get `exported & save` to the server on `specific folder` & later which I mail that file to the user as an attachment.

Did I have to make any change in my header for the same ?

For ref below is the header from my export excel library:

```
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$this->filename"); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
  header("Expires: 0"); 
  print "$header\n$data";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you really need to do is save the Excel contents to disk on your server, you can also remove those headers completely as they are only needed when outputting the data to the browser.

When you mail the user, simply attach the file and send.

It should be pretty straight forward.

EDIT:

To save the excel file:

`file_put_contents('<your file name>', '<your file contents>');`

The content can be any string, so if you have the excel file contents in a variable, simple put it there.

The file name can be a relative or absolute path.

Comment: I dont think without header it will generate a excel fie alos.

Comment: Also , where should & how i give the path to save exported excel file  ?

Comment: Obviously you'd need to use a library that generates excel files in the correct format, you don't need the headers for that.

Comment: what library are you using to currently generate the xsl file? Or where are you getting the contents from?

Comment: @Rikesh - it isn't the headers that make your file an Excel file, they simply tell the browser to expect an Excel file... you must already have an Excel file in the first place to send to the browser after the headers. So instead of echoing that file to the browser, you write it to file using file_put_contents() as Sean has said, and output a message to the browser instead, tellingg them that their file will be emailed to them.

Comment: @RikeshShah if this answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted incase someone else has a similar issue.